# Running Python code: subprocess.check_output(), getting error: [Winerror 2]

Tags: python, maven

I'm running some Python code that is meant to run an Apache Maven program on a file and produce an output:

```
import os, subprocess
os.chdir("C:/Users/Mohammad/Google Drive/PhD/Spyder workspace/production-consumption/logtool-examples/")
logtoolDir = "C:/Users/Mohammad/Google Drive/PhD/Spyder workspace/production-consumption/logtool-examples/"
processEnv = {'JAVA_HOME': 'C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_66/jre',
          'mvn': 'C:/Program Files/apache-maven-3.3.3/bin/'}
#processEnv = "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_66"
args = 'org.powertac.logtool.example.ProductionConsumption D:/PowerTAC/Logs/2015/log/powertac-sim-1.state testrunoutput.data'
subprocess.check_output(['mvn', ' exec:exec',
                             ' -Dexec.args=' + args],
                             env = processEnv,
                             cwd = logtoolDir)
```

However, it gives me this error:

```
File "C:/Users/Mohammad/Google Drive/PhD/Spyder workspace/production-consumption/test.py", line 25, in <module>
cwd = logtoolDir)

File "C:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.6\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\subprocess.py", line 607, in check_output
with Popen(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, **kwargs) as process:

File "C:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.6\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\subprocess.py", line 859, in __init__
restore_signals, start_new_session)

File "C:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.6\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\subprocess.py", line 1112, in _execute_child
startupinfo)

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I've investigated some things and I've narrowed it down to what I'm expecting is _winapi.CreateProcess being unable to *find* the Apache Maven installation (and run the *mvn* command). The installation is already in my path env variables (the line runs just fine through CMD). It may also be true that I've somehow defined the directories wrongly, but I fail to find a problem there... Can anyone offer a suggestion on how to fix this issue?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try appending "shell = True" to the arguments passed to subprocess like so:

```
subprocess.check_output(['mvn', ' exec:exec',
                         ' -Dexec.args=' + args],
                         env = processEnv,
                         cwd = logtoolDir, shell = True)
```

Though as it says [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments), this can be a security risk if the contents of the call can be determined by an external source, but I can't tell whether that's the case from the code you've given.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That indeed fixed that issue, but now I'm having another problem running the code. I think it's a problem with how check_process is sending the args to the command line. Error is:

CalledProcessError: Command '['mvn', 'exec:exec', '-Dexec.args="org.powertac.logtool.example.ProductionConsumption D:/PowerTAC/Logs/2015/log/powertac-sim-1.state testrunoutput.data"']' returned non-zero exit status 1

Comment: Not sure I can really help, it might be worth posting a new question with more details. There is some information in the link I provided but I can't find much in the way of a solution.

Comment: Thanks minl, I've posted the new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33808540/python-function-subprocess-check-output-returns-calledprocesserror-command-retu