# Python function subprocess.check_output returns CalledProcessError: command returns non-zero exit status

Tags: python, maven

As a follow-up to my previous question, which got solved quickly, I'm running the Python code below in WinPython:

```
import os, subprocess
os.chdir("C:/Users/Mohammad/Google Drive/PhD/Spyder workspace/production-consumption/logtool-examples/")
logtoolDir="C:/Users/Mohammad/Google Drive/PhD/Spyder workspace/production-consumption/logtool-examples/ "
#processEnv = {'JAVA_HOME': 'C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_66/'}
args = r'"org.powertac.logtool.example.ProductionConsumption D:/PowerTAC/Logs/2015/log/powertac-sim-1.state testrunoutput.data"'
subprocess.check_output(['mvn', 'exec:exec', '-Dexec.args=' + args],
                             shell = True, cwd = logtoolDir)
```

And get the following error:

```
CalledProcessError: Command '['mvn', 'exec:exec', '-Dexec.args="org.powertac.logtool.example.ProductionConsumption D:/PowerTAC/Logs/2015/log/powertac-sim-1.state testrunoutput.data"']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

The Apache Maven executable does not seem to run. My guess is that the arguments are being passed on to the program incorrectly. I couldn't find any typos in the *args* or the *logtoolDir* arguments, but maybe I'm missing something there? Any ideas?

UPDATE:
The mvn exec:exec was not running because `check_output` has somehow been unable to access Windows' environmental variables. I added the *path* variable to `processEnv` and now `'mvn','--version'` in the `check_output` args confirms Maven runs. The code still doesn't run but I imagine it's probably an issue with how I've defined the directories.

Cheers.

Comment: IIRC, if you use `shell=True`, generally you pass the args as a single string.

Comment: (also, never use `shell=True` for any reason.)

Comment: @Wooble -- that statement might be a  _bit_ strong :-).  There are times when it is convenient.  However, any code which uses it should _clearly_ document that the inputs need to be 100% trustworthy.

Comment: There are times when writing bad code is more convenient, sure. That doesn't mean you should do it. Presumably a lot of people find writing SQL injectable code more convenient than parameterizing, too.

Comment: @Wooble @mgilson I have used `shell = True` but that has not fixed this issue. Unfortunately I don't know any way around using it, since I need some environment variables (for the "mvn" command). The code is meant for personal data analysis so security is not a critical matter.
Regarding the issue itself, if `shell = True` forces a single string of args, I can't wrap my head around where the problem may lie... :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Basically: a) `subprocess.check_output` could not read Windows' environment variables (e.g. PATH, JAVA_HOME), so I had to redefine the one I was using in `processEnv` and pass it along in the function's arguments. Also, b) The *args* variable was defined incorrectly. I needed to remove one set of quotation marks, and also make it raw using `r`.

The corrected code:

```
logtoolDir='C:/Users/Mohammad/Google Drive/PhD/Spyder workspace/production-consumption/logtool-examples/'
processEnv = {'JAVA_HOME': 'C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_66/jre/',
          'Path' : 'C:/Program Files/apache-maven-3.3.3/bin/'}
args = r"org.powertac.logtool.example.ProductionConsumption D:/PowerTAC/Logs/2015/log/powertac-sim-1.state testrunoutput2.data"
print(subprocess.check_output(['mvn', 'exec:exec', '-Dexec.args='+ args],
                           shell = True, env = processEnv, cwd = logtoolDir))
```

Unfortunately I can't find a way to go around using the `shell = True` argument, which probably won't be a problem since this will only be used for data analysis.

Cheers.